# how to use data from ajax success in another function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i want to call jquery ajax function inside the function like this:

```
function mine(time){

$.get("test.php", function(data){
var mytime=data;
});           

alert(mytime);
}
```

it just print undefined.
my test.php file is this:

```
<?php echo time(); ?>
```

i want that value of 'mydata' is current time of php server.

Comment: Simple: Put or call every code that has to work with the response (from) *inside* the callback.

Comment: but i need to setinterval of that function.. .so i can't put inside.. .is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function gets executed at a later time. Instead of `document.write` at, use jQuery's methods:

```
$.get("test.php", function(data){
   var mytime=data;

   // Replace 'body' with a selector for the element that displays time
   $('body').text(mytime);

   // Alternatively, call another function
   someOtherFunction(mytime);
});
```

Comment: i don't want to display 'mytime' in body... but i want to use this variable in another javascript function.. .

Comment: @Kartik it Well, then simply call the other JavaScript function. Updated answer with an example.

Comment: @Kartikit: You have to rethink about your flow. Make the function accept a callback which gets executed once the result is available. JavaScript makes it very easy to implement things like this.

Comment: but i have setInterval of every 5 sec. for calling the function mine(), so i have to call ajax inside my function? is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Kartikit No, you call your function from the AJAX handler inside `mine`. As Felix said, that's totally natural in JavaScript.

Comment: @Kartikit: Why don't you get the time of the server *once* and then increment that time by 5 seconds? Why do you have to connect to the server again? It is not difficult to combine `setTimeout` with Ajax calls, but the question is whether you have to do that at all (and it does not seems to be the case).

Answer (score 0):

There may be chance of variable scope so define your variable like this

```
var mytime;
function mine(time){
    $.get("test.php", function(data){
        mytime=data;
    });           

    document.write(mytime);
}
```

Comment: This won't work, since the callback is executed at a later time than `document.write` is.

Comment: That wouldn't work, you'd have to move the `document.write` inside the success function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use synchrone mode

```
function validerServeur(value) { 
    var retval; 
    $.ajax( 
        url: "test.php", 
        data: { valeur: value }, 
        async: false,  // <--  This disable asynchrone mdoe
        succes: function(data) { 
            retval = data;
        } 
    ) ;
    return retval; 
}
```

Comment: Don't make synchronous calls!

Answer (score 0):

add the document.write(time) INSIDE the $.get 's handler like:

```
$.get("test.php", function(data){
var mytime=data;
document.write(mytime);
});
```

Comment: sorry! iN that case use echo time(); as you instructed. Just move the document.write inside the function handler as shown above.